# Number of ways to distribute gifts among kids subject to the stated conditions

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many ways we can distribute gifts among kids with conditions below.

Given the conditions:

There are 5 kids, denoted as A, B, C, D, and E.

There are 6 gifts, denoted as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6.

Only 3 kids will be given gifts.

Each kid can only have 1 gift.

Each gift can only be given to 1 kid.

Kid A doesn't like gifts 2 and 3.

Kid B doesn't like gift 2.

Kid D doesn't like gifts 1, 4, and 5.

---

We can select 10 kids to receive gifts from a pool of $\begin{pmatrix}5 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}=10$ children. However, considering that each child may have preferences or dislikes for certain gifts, every combination becomes distinct which become difficult. Are there faster approach?

Comment: There is no question posted in the problem. Do you need to find the number of ways to distribute gifts?

Comment: @Aig yes I'm looking for a simpler method than mine

Comment: I don’t understand this part at all: *We can select $10$ kids to receive gifts from a pool of $\binom{5}{3}$ children*.

Comment: @Aig Only three gifts must be given so we can choose $\binom{5}{3}$ different kids.

Comment: Ah, you meant triples of kids. There are only $5$ kids, but $10$ triples of kids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $\binom53$ ways to choose kids who will get gifts. There are $\binom63$ ways to choose gifts that will be presented. There are $3!$ ways to distribute them among $3$ chosen kids ignoring the prohibitions. In total, $\binom53\cdot\binom63\cdot3!$ ways.

Now we begin correcting this answer using the inclusion-exclusion principle. The gift $2$ was chosen and presented to the kid A. How many ways to do that? We choose $2$ more gifts, give them to $2$ kids. $\binom42\cdot\binom52\cdot2!$ ways to do it. There are $6$ prohibited pairs kid-gift. So the answer became $\binom53\cdot\binom63\cdot3! - 6\cdot \binom42\cdot\binom52\cdot2!$ at the moment.

Now we add the arrangements where two kids got undesired gifts. If those are A and B then they got gifts $3$ and $2$ respectively. Any of the $3$ other kids grabbed any of the $4$ other gifts. $3\cdot4$ ways to do that.

If A and D got bad gifts, then there are $2\cdot 3$ ways to do that. And the third kid gets any other gift, $3\cdot4$ ways to do that. If B and D got bad gifts, then there are $3$ ways to do that, and $3\cdot4$ ways to give a gift to the third kid.

Our answer became $\binom53\cdot\binom63\cdot3! - 6\cdot \binom42\cdot\binom52\cdot2! + (1+ 2\cdot 3 + 3)\cdot3\cdot4$ now. All we are left to do is to subtract cases when everyone got a gift they didn’t want. B got $2$, A got $3$. And D got one of the three. So $3$ cases. The final answer is then

$$\binom53\cdot\binom63\cdot3! - 6\cdot \binom42\cdot\binom52\cdot2! + (1+ 2\cdot 3 + 3)\cdot3\cdot4 - 3=$$

$$=597.$$

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use a variation of the theory of [Rook Polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook_polynomial).

In the board below, the columns correspond to kids and the rows to gifts; a shaded square indicates a forbidden combination.

$\qquad\qquad$   [image]

We will find the rook polynomial of the forbidden sub-board (the shaded squares): the polynomial
$$R(x) = \sum_{k>= 0} r_k x^k$$
where $r_k$ is the number of ways to place $k$ non-attacking rooks on the shaded squares.  By inspection, the shaded squares in the first two columns have the rook polynomial $1+3x+x^2$ and the shaded squares in column four have the rook polynomial $1+3x$.  Since these two groups have no row or column in common, the rook polynomial of the forbidden sub-board is
$$R(x) = (1+3x+x^2)(1+3x) = 1+6x+10x^2+3x^3 \tag{*}
$$

We are now ready to apply inclusion/exclusion to solve the problem.  Let's say an assignment of gifts to kids has "property $ij$" if kid $i$ is given gift $j$ where that combination is forbidden. We want to count all the assignments with none of the properties.  We define $S_k$ to be the total number of assignments with $k$ of the properties, for $0 \le k \le 3$.  Then

$$S_k = r_k \binom{5-k}{3-k} \binom{6-k}{3-k} (3-k)!$$
where the $r_k$ is the coefficient of $x^k$ in $(*)$.

By inclusion/exclusion, the number of assignments of three gifts to kids with no kid assigned a forbidden gift is
$$S_0-S_1+S_2-S_3 = 597$$